How to download a python whl file requiring a different version of python to the one available on the system
I am trying to download a whl file. The only problem is that there's a version constraint on the install. And this constraint on the install, also constrains the download too. This question is how from the client side i can get around this constraint so i can download the whl file.
In this project there is a pyproject.toml file he has specified requires-python = ">=3.10" constraint. I don't have write access to this repository, however i can read it, and asking the person to change this parameter is impossible, as they are uncooperative.
Now, i want to download, but not install, the whl file onto my dev system with python 3.8 installed. Installing and making python 3.10 the default python on this system isn't an option. How do i tell pip to ignore the version requirement so i can download the whl file, and without having to install a 3.10 virtual environment just to download the file each time.
If i download it directly i get this error:
...# pip download XXXX==0.2.18
Looking in indexes: ...
Collecting XXXX==0.2.18
  Downloading .../XXXX.whl (50 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 50 kB 2.0 MB/s 
  Saved ./XXXX.whl
ERROR: Package 'XXXX' requires a different Python: 3.8.10 not in '>=3.10'

The file that was downloaded is incomplete and not the whl package i need which should be ~500KB or so.
If i try and ignore the version number using the --ignores-requires-python parameter it gives me an error, apparently this parameter is only available for pip install but not pip download, e.g:
...# pip download --ignore-requires-python XXXX==0.2.18

Usage:   
  pip download [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  pip download [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  pip download [options] <vcs project url> ...
  pip download [options] <local project path> ...
  pip download [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --ignore-requires-python

Looking around further there's an option for specifying the --python-version, however it opens up a bunch of error messages:
...# pip download --python-version 3.10 XXXX==0.2.18
ERROR: When restricting platform and interpreter constraints using --python-version, --platform, --abi, or --implementation, either --no-deps must be set, or --only-binary=:all: must be set and --no-binary must not be set (or must be set to :none:).

I can't find any meaningful information on how to use this option, presumably because the assumption is that people might try and install using it, and the download use case hasn't been adequately considered by the python developers.
I have tried:
...# pip download --python-version 3.10 --no-deps XXXX==0.2.18
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, ...
Collecting XXXX==0.2.18
  File was already downloaded /.../XXXX.whl
Successfully downloaded XXXX

However this file is the incomplete file, of only 52KB size and is unusable. Similarly i have tried --only-binary=:all: with no luck.
How can i download the whl file on a python 3.8 system? Is it possible?

"I don't have write access to this repository" Why not just clone the repository locally, change the parameter, and re-build the wheel yourself? To me, that would be a much easier way around this issue, and I'm not quite sure where you've got the idea that just because you don't have write access to the source code repository itself doesn't mean you can't make this type of change to get it working in your particular use case.

Zooming out just a touch, if the author of the wheel in question has explicitly called out that a specific minimum Python version is required, do you believe that implicit assertion to be erroneous? Typically, there are pretty good reasons why one would set a minimum Python version on their package. Even if you do decide to rebuild the wheel yourself locally, that won't magically fix whatever compatibility issues there are with earlier versions of Python and this package (or its dependencies therein).

"Installing and making python 3.10 the default python on this system isn't an option." You do not need to make the python the default python. You can build python from source and install it in your user directory and then use that as a base to make virtual environment. You can also use things like docker to work on python versions that are not the system python.

@esqew yes it's reasonable if you're installing it. It isn't going to run on a machine with python 3.8 that's fair enough. The issue is that i'm not installing it, i'm downloading it to use as part of another piece of software. And i can get it working by creating virtual environments just to download the damn thing, but given that there are options in python to ignore versions and dependencies etc it seems like there should be an easier way using use parameters somehow. Ironically it seems that if you were installing rather than downloading it would install.

@Dunes yeah so that's what i'm doing at the moment i'm creating a virtual environment each time, just to download the file. It just seems that there should be a much easier way, and something that i can more easily explain to our sysadmin.

If you just want a single whl file (no dependencies), then you can do
pip download --no-deps --python-version 3.10 numpy==1.24

or
pip download --only-binary=:all: --python-version 3.10 numpy==1.24

to also download dependencies (only works though if all dependencies can be found as whl files)

Thank you for your answer, it does download it, but it downloads an incomplete 50KB file without all the internal whl binaries and everything compiled into bytecode rather than the full 500KB ish sized file. And that's the case with both commands. This is a really weird problem.

Thanks for confirming that i've been doing the right thing :)

That is indeed weird, I don't know what might be the cause of that, probably an issue in whatever library pip uses to download packages. You can make a new question that is solely about that topic "pip download only downloads 50kb" and/or post on the pip github to get the attention of someone who knows more

Yes i suspect that because there's precompiled binaries for python in the repository that i can't build because the tooling is outside of the repository, somehow that's getting silently blocked on the download. Anyway, i really appreciate the answer because this is going to be a question that comes up a lot, and i've found very little info on it on the internet :) Because generally people install the whl file directly.
